# Browser tab getting closed immediately after requesting a URL with seleniumrequests

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

Whenever I request any page using selenium-requests, the page just opens in the automated chrome tab and then closes automatically in a glimpse.

CODE

```
from seleniumrequests import Chrome
webdriver=Chrome()
page=webdriver.request('GET','https://www.google.com/')
```

However, if I do it with just selenium then it works as expected

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/cryzed/Selenium-Requests/blob/master/seleniumrequests/request.py) you can see at the bottom of the request method, that seleniumrequests wrapper closes the tab after finishing the request or switches back to the original, which is not existent in your case.

```
    def request(self, method, url, **kwargs):
...
        # Don't keep cookies in the Requests session, only use the WebDriver's
        self.requests_session.cookies.clear()
        if opened_window_handle:
            self.close()
        if original_window_handle:
            self.switch_to.window(original_window_handle)

        return response
```

Pure Selenium does not close the webdriver implicitly. You have to do that yourself.